# How is the A320neo life span calculated?

Tags: airbus-a320, airbus-neo

I read an article saying that the new Airbus A320neo life span is based on monthly cycles instead of hours or takeoff landing cycles, is this correct?
If so can I understand how it’s calculated based on monthly span?
Any external documents explaining this method will be much appreciated
Thanks

Comment: You need to post a link to the article if possible please.